# aws cli get emr cluster and steps

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, aws-cli, amazon-emr

Goal: Retrieve AWS EMR clusters with name, id, starttime, endtime, step id, instance sizes, and step ID where status change reason is all steps completed and the clusters are created after a specific date (and time, if possible) using a command/shell script using AWS CLI.

So far, I have the following:

```
aws emr list-clusters --created-after 2023-06-25 -query "Clusters[?Status.StateChangeReason.Code==`ALL_STEPS_COMPLETED`].{ID:Id, Cluster: Name, Created: Status.Timeline.CreationDateTime, Ended: Status.Timeline.EndDateTime}"
```

Also, the following is my current starting point which just gets me steps and fails for the last or the oldest cluster with a syntax error

```
aws emr list-clusters --created-after 2023-06-25 -query "Clusters[?Status.StateChangeReason.Code==`ALL_STEPS_COMPLETED`].Id --output text | xargs -n1 | xargs {} aws emr list-steps --cluster-id {} --query Steps[*].Id
```

Comment: `Retrieve AWS EMR clusters with name, ... and step ID` What step ID do you mean? There may be multiple steps.

Comment: I am interested in just the first step, for now.